# Setting Google's protobuf environment for java in windows 64bit

Tags: java, protocol-buffers

I have spend 2 hours to search how I can setup the protobuf in windows for java. I really tied by searching and didn't find any way. Some say download the binary `protoc.exe` from https://github.com/google/protobuf/releases and some say download the source code then generate the binary.

I stopped my self by searching after reading about each page related to this from first google search. But still didn't find a way to solve it. There is no `protoc.exe` file in google release page and I don't know how I can create it because I don't have good experience in C++ ( Just know the basics ).

So I posted the question here to get help. Please let me know how I can download `protoc.exe` file. If not then how I can create it? I just downloaded `protobuf-java-3.4.1.zip` from [google release page](https://github.com/google/protobuf/releases).

Comment: Are you using Maven? If yes, you don't even need a binary, you need a Maven plugin. I the [comoyo](https://github.com/comoyo/commons/tree/master/protoc-bundled-plugin/) one, or the [os72](https://github.com/os72/protoc-jar-maven-plugin) one.

Comment: No I'm using simple java to test/learn protobuff.

Comment: The [3.4.0](https://github.com/google/protobuf/releases/tag/v3.4.0) release contains the pre-built binaries. They just did not re-release them for 3.4.1 as nothing changed. Also, here's everything: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/protobuf/protoc/

Answer (score 2):

You can find the precompiled binary on the [3.4.0 release](https://github.com/google/protobuf/releases/tag/v3.4.0).

The archive to download for windows is `protoc-3.4.0-win32.zip`.

The `3.4.1` release contains only minor bugfixes, so they probably didn't bother to create the binary for it.

Comment: what if I really want to build 3.4.1? can you add step by step guide, because google's README file confusing me due to my less knowledge about such environment setting.

Answer (score 0):

Download the package for CPP from the github
https://github.com/google/protobuf/releases/tag/v3.4.1

Below is the download link,
https://github.com/google/protobuf/releases/download/v3.4.1/protobuf-cpp-3.4.1.zip
Extract it, goto "cmake" directory and read the readme.md doc.
It lists line by line procedure for windows environment setup.

Comment: Hi I tried it but still confused because some terms and steps are totally irrelevant or I'm unable to understand..